# Ionic Framework interferes with contenteditable divs + WYSIWYG editors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, trix

Ionic framework (v 1.3) is interfering with `contenteditable = 'true'` DIVs. As far as I can tell it is preventing my click and drag events from propagating properly, which (in my case) is preventing me from using pretty much any WYSIWYG text editor.

I am unable to focus the cursor in a `contenteditable` DIV, nor am I able to select text from one. When I use the Trix editor (which also uses this), I can get an initial focus, but cannot place the cursor anywhere or select any text.

Is there a way to override Ionic's behavior here?

I have created a **[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/USRQioa3BB7wbArqpNB6?p=preview)** with two panes demonstrating the basic `contenteditable` issue and the issue in conjunction with the Trix editor.

Demonstration usage:

```
<ion-view title="ContentEditable Example">
  <ion-content class="has-header padding">
    <div contenteditable="true" style="user-select: all; -webkit-user-select: all;">
      <p>ContentEditable Text. This is a DIV with contenteditable set to true, AND user-select set to all. Note how you cannot click and edit the text!</p>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that enables the use of a `contenteditable` div as well as the Trix editor in Ionic. I applied this class to the CSS and am now not experiencing any issues, either testing in a browser or on a real device:

```
.editable{
    user-select: text; 
    -webkit-user-select: text; 
    pointer-events: all !important; 
    -webkit-user-modify:read-write !important;
}
```